# Animate table column to hide/show it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a very simple table, i try to animate the first column if i press on it.

[image: Full table]

After the click it should animate to the left, so that it is not fully displayed anymore:

[image: animated]

Then after another click, it should animate back again

[image: animated back again]

I tried to achieve this with jquery, but nothing happens:

```js
var main = function()
{
    $boolean = true;
    
    $(".test").click
    (
       function()
       {
          if ($boolean)
         {
             $boolean = false;
             $(".test").animate
             (
                {
                   'left':'-=100px'
                },
                "fast"
             );  
           }
          else
          {
                $boolean = true;
                $(".test").animate
                (
                    {
                        'left':'+=100px'
                    },
                    "fast"
                );  
           }    
       }
  );
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.test {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <th class="test">Filename</th>
  <th>value</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="test">File1</td>
  <td>Test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="test">File1</td>
  <td>Test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="test">File1</td>
  <td>Test</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Why is it not animating and how can i solve it? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working solution:

```js
var main = function()
{
    $boolean = true;
    
    $(".test").click
    (
       function()
       {
          if ($boolean)
         {
             $boolean = false;
             $(".test").animate
             (
                {
                   'max-width':'10px'
                },
                "fast"
             );  
           }
          else
          {
                $boolean = true;
                $(".test").animate
                (
                    {
                        'max-width':'300px'
                    },
                    "fast"
                );  
           }    
       }
  );
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.test {
    color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <th class="test">Filename</th>
  <th>value</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="test">File1</td>
  <td>Test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="test">File1</td>
  <td>Test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="test">File1</td>
  <td>Test</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zcb0a9tz/

Answer (score 1):

If you add on more animating property like opacity, you will see that it works. So animation is working.

```
$(".test").click
(
   function()
   {
      if ($boolean)
      {
         $boolean = false;
         $(".test").animate
         (
            {  opacity: 0.5,
               'left':'-=100px'
            },
            "fast"
         );  
       }
       else
       {
            $boolean = true;
            $(".test").animate
            (
                {   opacity: 0.25,
                    'left':'+=100px'
                },
                "fast"
            );  
       }    
   }
);
```

Try this and you will see animation working.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a fixe witdth to your table and add this property :

```
  table-layout: fixed;
  width:200px;
```

And then you can use this javascript :

```
var main = function()
{
    $boolean = true;

      $(".test").click(function(){
                if($boolean){
              $boolean = false;
              $( ".test" ).animate({ 
                  width:"20px",
                }, 1500 );
             } else {
                    $boolean = true;
                $( ".test" ).animate({ 
                  width:"100px",
                }, 1500 );
             }
      });
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

You can see [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccfnojf6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to animate width not left property. 
Try this one :

```
var main = function(){
  $boolean = true;
  $(".test").click(function(){
    if ($boolean){
      $boolean = false;
      $(".test").animate({'width':'-=50px'},"fast");  
    }else{
      $boolean = true;
     $(".test").animate({'width':'+=50px'},"fast");  
    }    
  }
)}
```

Additionally you should change css for .test like this:

```
.test {
  color: red;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change `left` or `top` for `position: static` elements. Try making them `relative` position to preserve their real position.

```js
var main = function() {
  $boolean = true;

  $(".test").click(
    function() {
      if ($boolean) {
        $boolean = false;
        $(".test").animate({
            'left': '-=100px'
          },
          "fast"
        );
      } else {
        $boolean = true;
        $(".test").animate({
            'left': '+=100px'
          },
          "fast"
        );
      }
    }
  );
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.test {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="test">Filename</th>
    <th>value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="test">File1</td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="test">File1</td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="test">File1</td>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```